# How to get the latitude & longitude of the 4 corners of the map being displayed

Tags: openlayers, latitude-longitude

I am working on OpenLayers (ol3) and I want to get the Latitude, Longitude of the corners of the map being shown at a point. I tried using `map.getView().getProjection().getExtent()` and converting the points from 'EPSG:3857' to 'EPSG:4326' but I get `-180,-85.05112877980659,180,85.05112877980659` irrespective of the zoom level of the map I have set.

I would like to know the map view corner points dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the current extent with:

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

Then you can use [ol.proj.transformExtent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.proj.html?unstable=true#transformExtent) to reproject the extent.

Comment: link is now: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transformExtent

Answer (score 6):

The available answers didn't work easily so I'm pasting my solution:

```
var glbox = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()); // doesn't look as expected.
var box = ol.proj.transformExtent(glbox,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'); // this looked like what I expected.
```

Comment: If I'm thinking in a right way, lat and lon for four corners should be 8 numbers!
but this code returns 4 number, what are these?

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a while, but it only takes 4 numbers to define a box: top, bottom, left, and right. Maybe it is giving you the edges instead of the corner points. You can recombine these to get the points if you need them. Also that could be totally wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are retrieving the extent of the projection, and not the current map.

You could try [getExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getExtent):

```
map.getExtent();
```

This returns a [bounds object](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.transform) that can be transformed to give lat lon.

Comment: This is for OpenLayers 2, for OpenLayers 3 use `map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean the extent of the View at any zoom or center.
*Btw I have all my layers in 4326 so no convertion need it.*

I use this to avoid pan the map outside an area. 
If you know map.size (that is html div size) and resolution (that depend on zoom) you can know how big is your Extent.
Then using your center you can calculate all corners.

```
var maxExtent = [-79.59975, -1.200, -53.03076, 13.72883];
view.on('change:center', function (evt) {
    var center = view.getCenter();
    var x = center[0];
    var y = center[1];
    var resolution = view.getResolution();
    var mapSize = map.getSize();

    var mapHalfWidth = (mapSize[0] * resolution) / 2.0;
    var mapHalfHeight = (mapSize[1] * resolution) / 2.0;

    if (center[0] - mapHalfWidth < maxExtent[0]) {
        x = maxExtent[0] + mapHalfWidth;
    } else if (center[0] + mapHalfWidth > maxExtent[2]) {
        x = maxExtent[2] - mapHalfWidth;
    }
    if (center[1] - mapHalfHeight < maxExtent[1]) {
        y = maxExtent[1] + mapHalfHeight;
    } else if (center[1] + mapHalfHeight > maxExtent[3]) {
        y = maxExtent[3] - mapHalfHeight;
    }

    if (center[0] != x || center[1] != y) {
        view.setCenter([x, y]);
    }
});
```